# encode special character in URL

Tags: java, urlencode, uribuilder

```
{URL}/text=Congratulations%21+You+are+eligible+for+.%0A
```

`%0A` = New line encoded character

I am passing encoded new line syntax in parameter. But the problem is that when I am building the above URL then its again encoded the `% as %25`
so above URL become `{URL}/text=Congratulations%21+You+are+eligible+for+.%250A`

I am not able to understand why URLBuilder encode already encoded character.

Used below code for building URLBuilder

```
URI url = new URIBuilder("URL").build();
```

Comment: I don't know about that, but you could use Java 8's Base64 class (Base64.getUrlEncoder() etc) to encode your text in a way that will never be transformed further on the way through the system. It's wasteful because it doubles the length, but it's otherwise a one-size-fits-all solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need url encoding why do you use  URIBuilder at all? You could simply create a new URI.

Answer (score 0):

You need [#buildFromEncoded](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html#buildFromEncoded-java.lang.Object...-) if you want to feed in pre-encoded strings.